# PostgreSQL- ERROR: column XXX does not exist

Tags: postgresql

I am completely new to PostgreSQL. I have a table with next columns:

```
db_1=# select * from table1 where false;  
 id | createdat | description | index | name | updatedat | type_id |dtype 
----+-----------+-------------+-------+------+-----------+---------+-----  
(0 rows)
```

Where content is like this:

```
db_1=# select id,name,dtype from table1;  
id |  name   |  dtype  
---+---------+--------------  
1  |  name1  | PlantControl  
2  |  name2  | PlantSystem  
3  |  name3  | PlantControl  
4  |  name4  | PlantControl  
5  |  name5  | PlantSystem  
6  |  name6  | AlarmSystem  
7  |  name7  | AlarmSystem  
(7rows)
```

If I try to delete every row with `dtype=PlantSystem`, I have next error:

> ```
> db_1=# delete from table1 where dtype=PlantControl;  
> ERROR:  column "plantcontrol" does not exist  
> LINE 1: delete from table1 where dtype=PlantControl;
> ```

Obviously, `PlantControl` is not a column, the column is `dtype` ...

Answer (score 3):

You need to quote the value  PlantControl.

```
delete from table1 where dtype='PlantControl';
```

Comment: In case it could help someone, it must be single quotes (not double quotes)